# no output after depacking C packed script with UPX

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, upx, x64dbg

I learn how to pack then unpack scripts with UPX and C language. Here is my script which I packs:
[image]

it is quite simple, just types string "hello world" on a screen. Well, I pack it using next commands:

```
gcc -m32 main.c -o main
upx main.exe -o main-upx.exe
```

And it all works fine for me, here is the output of DIE

[image]

As you can see, here I get that PE is packed with UPX (`best` option, but it does not matter).
The next thing which I do is opening the packed file with x64dbg (x32 mode).
There I find **popad** rule, and after some commands I reach actual unpacked entry point of the application. Here it is:
[image]

I am sure that this is actual entry point, because when I execute all code which is bellow until it works fine, here is the result of execution:

[image]

Well, after it, when I found the actual point, from where the program runs, I try to create a dump of memmory with built-in application **Scylla**:

[image]

Steps which i do:

1. Insert in OEP my new entry point, for me it is **005E14C0**
2. Secondly, I click button *IAT Autosearch*
3. Then I click **Get imports**
4. Next step is dumping the memmory with selected settings, I click *dump* and save the file as **main-upx_dump.exe**
5. After that all, I just click the last button which is **Fix Dump** to fix imports table and also save the file.

The next step which I do, is running the .exe, and when I starts it in `cmd`, the output which i receive is nothing, just an empty string, here it is:

[image]

I just cannot get what am i doing wrong, if you know what could go wrong, please, write an answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: There can be many reasons. Your test application is small, disassemble it to figure out what code it contains. When the code is correct (contains printf "hello world"), run it in a debugger to see what it does.

Comment: I did it today well there is something really wrong with SCY file which i receive after fixes of imports table. dump file contains exactly what i need, but SCY does not